# Инструмент для визуализации плана выполнения SQL скрипта (создания протоитпа)

Tags: sql, диаграммы, etl

У меня есть SQL скрипт(прототип) на 4.5к строк, который должен быть переписан на ETL фреймворке и возникла проблема чтобы его эффективно распараллелить.
Этот скрипт берет данные из 20 источников, обрабатывает их в течении 80 промежуточных шагов, которые также соединяются друг с другом и выдает 4 целевые таблицы с данными.
В Notepad++ есть плагин, позволяющий распарсить SQL в нужный мне результат, однако он очень неудобный и костыльный (нельзя перемещать шаги на диаграмме, нельзя масштабировать).

Получившаяся схема с правками в пейнте - https://i.imgur.com/bNoxyWB.jpg

Та же схема, но с источниками - https://i.imgur.com/sbovnGy.jpg

Есть ли сайты\инструменты\фреймворки, позволяющие достичь такой же диаграммы, но с возможностью, как минимум перемещать эти шаги в рабоей области, чтобы явно разделить эту лапшу на ветки? Если бы балы возможность явно прописать время создания каждой таблицы (каждого шага) и получить диаграмму, распределённую по времени - была бы вообще сказка.
Есть ли что-то подобное?